# consult with scraping. Request and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, request

I want to scrape to [this web page](http://propertyfinder.ae). The problem is that I do not know if it is convenient to do it with requests or selenium. When I enter the link of a house, and
I want to take the email, this is at the end of the source as a gray script, and I do not know how to take it.

I tried something like:

```
re.search(s, response.text)
print(result)
```

Under the body there are a lot information in the gray .., and there are the email... in this case is yasirjunejo@hotmail.com" . You can not see it in the website... you need to go to the PageSource. I want to take this email

but it's not working.

Comment: You'll need to add more code for us to help you!

Comment: @EmanuelLemos What is your exact usecase?

Comment: i tried but stack has not allow me. the page is "https://m.propertyfinder.ae/en/rent/apartment-for-rent-abu-dhabi-corniche-road-etihad-towers-3215021.html" and i want to take the Email , there is in a gray script under the source

Comment: @DebanjanB I hope that can help you

Comment: @EmanuelLemos Which is that element exactly _i want to take the Email_? The text within the red button?

Comment: @DebanjanB Really thanks for help me , you are an amaizing person. Under de body there are a lot information in the gray <srcript>..</script>, and there are the email... in this case is yasirjunejo@hotmail.com" . You can not see it in the website... you need to go to the PageSource

Comment: You said: "You can not see it in the website ..." In that case Selenium will not be a good tool choice. Just grab the site source and parse it with some XML parser. BeautifulSoup seems to be a popular choice.